# Change database during execution Spring Boot using part of Http request Url

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I need to change the current used DB everytime there is a new Http request and its name is part of Http URL request.
I'm trying using the following code, but when I call the service and it's executing, I can't call again until the prevoius one has finished otherwise it crashes.
I noticed the problem is 'database not selected' but I don't know how the change DB without crashing :(
The database and tables must be created automatically by code if there aren't yet so I'm using Flyway.

I need to use a name which is passed from user by the url of the request
The Url pattern is:
.../api/v1/{db_name}/...
I'm using jdbcTemplate but JPA solutions are welcome :)

```
try {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = (DriverManagerDataSource) jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();

        String urlBase = env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
        dataSource.setUrl(urlBase);

        dataSource.setSchema(name);

         Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                        .dataSource(dataSource)
                        .defaultSchema(name)
                        .load();
         flyway.migrate();
         dataSource.setUrl(urlBase+name);
         return true;
   }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
   }`
```

The exception when I call the link twice from two different clients:

```
StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO statistiche_plu_giornaliere (id, id_dbLocale, idDevice, id_plu, descrizione, importo_totale, qta_totale_plu, qta_reso_storno, qta_reale, data, importo_sconti, importo_maggiorazioni, importo_reale, resi, id_reparto, tipo_riga)  VALUES (0,256,'0AB1115556633569',0,'1LT PROSECCO',24.000000,2.000000,0.000000,2.000000,'',0.000000,0.000000,24.000000,0.000000,0,0)]; SQL state [3D000]; error code [1046]; No database selected; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:558)
    at com.trei.statistiche_cloud.db.DbHandler.updateStatisticheGiornaliere(DbHandler.java:119)
    at com.trei.statistiche_cloud.http.RestController.aggiornaDb(RestController.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1334)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2084)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:546)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1UpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:543)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)`
```

Comment: *Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected*

Comment: I've already known, but how can I solve?

Comment: select a database?

Comment: That's the point, how could I do? If I get the name from http request url and modifing the datasource url using the code posted before, it crashes :(

Comment: You get the URL for flyway from an HTTTPService? sounds crazy. But anyway we need more information to help such like your configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think your use cases are highly dangerous since you are basically providing secrets of a database through HTTP/s calls other inconveniences are:

1. Loading a database for every request would significantly increase the response time of your application
2. Causes issues with scalability and resource consumption.

Instead, it's usually advised to set up your Spring Boot application to initiate a database connection as soon as it launches and to maintain it open for the rest of the program's lifetime. This strategy enables higher scalability and considerably quicker database access.

If there is a need to configure multiple databases for the same application you can manually define multiple data sources. Upon each request you can chose the database to query on